# ambiguous mysql statement using AND and OR need help to structure correctly

Tags: mysql

I have a sql statement that I already know is not structured correctly using a `SELECT` with `AND` and `OR`. I have tried several variations but I can't seem to get it to work. It is returning 18 records when it should be returning only 17.

```
SELECT * 
FROM xxx_activity 
WHERE (dest_id = '20321' OR dest_id = 0) 
      AND user_id != '20321' 
      AND department_id = 14 
      OR department_id = 15 
      OR department_id = 16 
      AND read_test NOT LIKE '%|20321|%' 
      AND org_code = '20321'
```

**Let me break down what I need**

- `dest_id` can only equal '20321' **OR** '0'
- `user_id` must **NOT** equal 20321
- `department_id` can only equal 14 **OR** 15 **OR** 16
- `read_test` must **NOT** be like `%|20321|%`
- `org_code` must equal 20321

Any help to structure this correctly?

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor (actually atrocious) design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention conditions for **code_org**, but i think this is what you want:

```
SELECT
 * 
FROM
 xxx_activity
WHERE
 dest_id in ('20321' , '0')
AND
 user_id != '20321'
AND
 department_id in (14 , 15 , 16)
AND
 read_test NOT LIKE '%|20321|%'
AND
 org_code = '20321'
```

Comment: your right I edited my question, trying your code now

Comment: I added the 'in' clauses kinda late - be sure you leverage them as well :)

Comment: btw, ID columns are usually a numeric, so the single quotes are most likely not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not grouping your condition properly

```
WHERE dest_id in ('20321' ,'0') 
AND user_id != '20321' 
AND department_id in (14 , 15 , 16)
AND read_test NOT LIKE '%|20321|%' 
AND org_code = '20321'
```